# preventDefault not working with tinyMCE keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

When binding on the 'keydown' event on a tinyMCE editor instance, calling preventDefault() on the event does not prevent the default behavior in the editor. For example, when capturing the ENTER key being pressed with the following code:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    setup: function (editor) {
        $(editor).on('keydown', function (event) {
            if (event.which == 13) {
                alert('enter pressed');
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

TinyMCE still inserts a line break. How can I override this behavior?

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
 if (event.which == 13) {
      alert('enter pressed');
      event.preventDefault();
 }
```

to

```
 if (event.which == 13) {
      alert('enter pressed');
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Ok, this works with vanilla TinyMCE but does not work with ui-tinymce for Angular. It appears to be an issue specifically with that Angular directive's broken ``setup`` callback.

Comment: were you able to solve the problem? the same thing happens to me in react

Comment: As a tip to others, I was trying to get this to work with keyup and it would only work with keydown.